# Non remote controlled ceiling fan turns off and on by itself

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan that we turn on each night as we go to bed. During the night it turns off for an intermittent amount of time and then back on by itself. It is not a ceiling fan with a remote control, it is older than that. We have checked the wires and cannot see anything in the ceiling fan that looks worn. Any suggestions?

We turn it on with a wall switch. There is no light in the fan.

Comment: To test if the fault is in the fan, remove the two wires from the wall switch and connect them with a wire nut. If the fault is in the fan, then the operation will be intermittent like now. If the fan runs continuously, the fault is in the wall switch and it should be replaced.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Any chance it has a thermostat in it? Does it run longer when it's warm?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a thermal cut if fan even has one.Running long periods of time motor getting to hot shuts down and when temp ok will run . If it is old fan may be best to replace fan.Motor may be on way out .

Comment: Time to get new fan. Or you .could leave it and have a house fire over old fan

Comment: Dan it may  have a thermostat ,  I doubt it and fan is old and needs to be replaced with new one. Before overload and fire.